# introducing myself to Closures: functions tied to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I had a little understanding of closure which, a function that can be stored as a variable (referred to as a "first-class function"), that has a special ability to access other variables local to the scope it was created in.

Somehow I had trouble how this code works, how does these independent functions messageForRahul/Greg gets executed inside the Inner function when they are not declared as a parameter?

```
var sendMessageTo = function (name) {

return function (message) {
    console.log ("Message for " + name + ": " + message);
}
};

var messageForRahul = sendMessageTo ("Rahul");
var messageForGreg = sendMessageTo ("Greg");


messageForRahul ("Hello, Rahul");
messageForGreg ("Hello, Greg");
```

Comment: Have you read the [MDN article on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Why did you expect the code not to work?

Comment: Beautiful article on closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Bergi The code works as it should

Comment: @CommercialSuicide: So then what don't you understand about it? What exactly do you want to know? "Help?" is not a question.

Comment: @Bergi It's NOT MY question)

Comment: @Bergi how does these messageForRahul/Greg gets executed inside the inner function or it calls the inner function by parameter message?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide: Oops, but then I don't understand your comment. Of course every code does what it is written to do (disregarding compiler/interpreter bugs), but something must have been unexpected/unclear to the OP.

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio: `messageForRahul` *is* the inner function that got returned. You could have equally declared it and then returned it by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you the **basic understanding**.

```
var messageForRahul = sendMessageTo("Rahul");
```

You create a variable that invokes the function `sendMessageTo` and passes to it the parameter `("Rahul")`.
Than you do the same thing with this line of code: `var messageForGreg = sendMessageTo("Greg");`

Now you have **two independent functions**, which were running with different parameters.

The line `messageForRahul("Hello, Rahul");` **runs your inner function** for function in which you **passed the parameter** `("Rahul")`.

As you can imagine, the last line of code **runs your inner function** for another function in which you **passed the parameter** `("Greg")`.

This code should help you to understand, what's happening. You can write the code this way:

```js
    var sendMessageTo = function(name) {
      return function(message) {
        console.log("Message for " + name + ": " + message);
      }
    };
    sendMessageTo("Rahul")("Hello, Rahul");
    sendMessageTo("Greg")("Hello, Greg");
```

First you invoke the outer function `sendMessageTo("Rahul")`, and then the inner function `("Hello, Rahul")`.

Comment: My english is a little confusing, but i hope you will get the main line. And feel free to improve this answer.

Comment: yes, that's what I don't understand, How does it get into/ get executed in the inner function scope?

Comment: @glendon philipp baculio I improved the answer, check this. And feel free to ask, if i didn't answer your question yet.

Comment: I was confused because they were not declared as a parameter.inside the inner function

Comment: `function(name)` in also a declaration of `var name` in the **scope** of the (this time anonymous) **function**. Read [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It is really interesting.